# Creating or saving many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

I've created a local RoR app to help scape front-end html content, store it, organize it, then put it into another DB. I'm currently starting the development of the organization and import of this content into another database. This has been going well except that I need to be able to save (or update if exists) the Post object's many-to-many relationship to term_taxonomy.

The following code (in controller):

```
def create_hierarchy post, content
    [...]
    @crumbs.each do |crumb|
        @term_attributes = {
            :name => crumb.strip,
            :slug => crumb.parameterize.split(' ').join('-').downcase
        }

        @term = Term.where(@term_attributes).first_or_initialize
        @term_taxonomy = TermTaxonomy.where({:term_id => @term.id, :taxonomy => 'category'}).first_or_initialize
        @term_taxonomy.posts << post
        @term.term_taxonomies << @term_taxonomy

        @term.save!
    end
    [...]
end
```

The code `@term_taxonomy.posts << post` results in error: `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry ...` when I run it *only after* the first time. The first time it runs, the many-to-many relationship between Term_taxonomy and Post saves successfully without issue.

What is the better way to perform a save (or update if post relationship exists) for the many-to-many relationship with term_taxonomy?

**UPDATE -**

Here are the relationships to the DB I'm importing to:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    [...]
    has_many    :term_relationships, :foreign_key => 'object_id', autosave: true
    has_many    :term_taxonomies, :through => :term_relationships
end

class TermRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    [...]
    belongs_to     :post, :foreign_key => "object_id"
    belongs_to     :term_taxonomy
    has_one :term, :through => :term_taxonomy
end

class TermTaxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
    [...]
    belongs_to  :term, autosave: true
    has_many    :term_relationships, :foreign_key => 'term_taxonomy_id'
    has_many    :posts, :through => :term_relationships
end

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
    [...]
    has_many    :term_taxonomies, foreign_key: 'term_id'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

This is what I changed my controller to:

```
def create_hierarchy post, content
    [...]
    @term_attributes = {
        :name => category_name.strip,
        :slug => @slug_builder += (@slug_builder.present? ? '-' : '') + slugify(category_name)
    }
    @term = Term.where(@term_attributes).first_or_create!

    @term_taxonomy_attributes = {
        :term_id => @term.id,
        :taxonomy => 'category'
    }
    @term_taxonomy = @term.term_taxonomies.where(@term_taxonomy_attributes).first_or_create!

    [...]

    # Add or update post
    if @term_taxonomy.posts.exists? post
        @term_taxonomy.posts.find(post.ID).update_attributes(post.attributes)
    else
        @term_taxonomy.posts << post
    end

    @term.save!
    @term_taxonomy.save!
end
```